# Swift Navigation Links in Menu

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation

I'm moving things around in my app. I have a view that allows users to upload photos which was initial a 'main tab feature. EX: 'A button on the bottom of the application no matter what area you are in within the app'.

I want to move this view to a menu that appears when a navigation bar icon is selected. when I embed the view in a button I get one of two errors. One is a binding error and one is an index error, but I'm not sure why this is happening. The signout button work without issue.

```
 //signout

  HStack {
       Spacer()
       
       Button("sign out  ") {
           AuthService.shared.signout()
       }
       .foregroundColor(.black)
       .font(.custom("AvenirNextCondensed-MediumItalic", size: 32))
       .bold()
   }

 // upload that does not work

  HStack {
       Spacer()
       
       NavigationLink(uploadPostView()) {
       Button("post to social  ") {
           
       }
       .foregroundColor(.black)
       .font(.custom("AvenirNextCondensed-MediumItalic", size: 32))
       .bold()
       .padding(.bottom, 40)
       
   }
}

 //the above gives me a tab index error
```

import SwiftUI

```
struct userMenuView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @StateObject var viewModel: userMenuViewModel

    init(user: User) {
        self._viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: userMenuViewModel(user: user))
    }

var body: some View {
           NavigationView {
               VStack {
                   //toolbar
                   VStack {
                       HStack {
                           Spacer()
                           
                           Spacer()
                           
                           Button("Close") {
                               dismiss()
                               
                           }
                           .foregroundColor(.black)
                           .fontWeight(.semibold)
                       }
                       .padding(.horizontal)
                       
                       Divider()
                   }
                   Spacer()
                   
                   // Buttons underneath the header
                   VStack {
                       
                       HStack {
                           Spacer()
                           Button("  ") {
                               // Handle Button A action
                           }
                           .foregroundColor(.black)
                           .font(.custom("AvenirNextCondensed-MediumItalic", size: 32))
                           .bold()
                           .padding(.bottom, 40)
                       }
                       
                       HStack {
                           Spacer()
                           
                           NavigationLink(uploadPostView()) {
                           Button("post to social  ") {
                               
                           }
                           .foregroundColor(.black)
                           .font(.custom("AvenirNextCondensed-MediumItalic", size: 32))
                           .bold()
                           .padding(.bottom, 40)
                           
                       }
                   }
                       
                       
                       HStack {
                           Spacer()
                           Button("  ") {
                               // Handle Button B action
                           }
                           .foregroundColor(.black)
                           .font(.custom("AvenirNextCondensed-MediumItalic", size: 32))
                           .bold()
                           .padding(.bottom, 40)
                       }
                       
                       HStack {
                           Spacer()
                           
                           Button("  ") {
                               // Handle Button C action
                           }
                           .foregroundColor(.black)
                           .font(.custom("AvenirNextCondensed-MediumItalic", size: 32))
                           .bold()
                           .padding(.bottom, 40)
                       }
                       
                       HStack {
                           Spacer()
                           
                           Button("  ") {
                               // Handle Button C action
                           }
                           .foregroundColor(.black)
                           .font(.custom("AvenirNextCondensed-MediumItalic", size: 32))
                           .bold()
                           .padding(.bottom, 40)
                       }
                       
                       HStack {
                           Spacer()
                           Button("  ") {
                               // Handle Button A action
                           }
                           .foregroundColor(.black)
                           .font(.custom("AvenirNextCondensed-MediumItalic", size: 32))
                           .bold()
                           .padding(.bottom, 40)
                       }
                       
                       HStack {
                           Spacer()
                           
                           Button("sign out  ") {
                               AuthService.shared.signout()
                           }
                           .foregroundColor(.black)
                           .font(.custom("AvenirNextCondensed-MediumItalic", size: 32))
                           .bold()
                       }
                       
                   }
                   .padding(.bottom, 30)
                   
               }
               .background(
                           Image("userm")
                               .resizable()
                               .scaledToFill()
                               .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                               
                       )
           }
       }
   }


 //this method works on any other page with navigation view. I am a beginner, but have tried a bunch of different things to resolve this.
```

Comment: Note, a `NavigationLink` is already a `Button`, there is no need for an additional `Button` view (which often creates problems when tapping). Use `Text("post to social  ")` instead of the `Button("post to social  ")`.

Comment: `I want to move this view to a menu that appears when a navigation bar icon is selected.`
Well why don't you show us that `menu` code with the `navigation bar` that gives you the errors.
 Show also the full error messages and on which lines they occur. Show enough of the code so we can replicate your errors.
 Do you have a `TabView` as well in the code you don't show?
 Note, `NavigationView` is deprecated, use `NavigationStack` instead.

Comment: I did not see any error. By the way, I've replaced your Buttons into NavigationLink with Text and embedded the entire View into a NavigationStack and everything seems to work fine.